Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
I am trying to install this but it always crashes and shows me this.


It seems that you are trying to install Ubuntu server (CLI edition). Do you really intend to install the CLI edition or do you want to install the GUI edition (which is Ubuntu Desktop)

Does anything happen when you click either the "View full log" or the "View error report" options? If you can get any more information by clicking these options please add it to your question.
